# How to persist enum types in postgres?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, enums

I want to persist the following xml structure in postgres:

```
<product>
  <type>car</type>
  <text>long content</text>
</product>
```

The `type` property could have about 10-20 variations. Thus, in java they will be `enums`.

I could create a `table product` as follows:

```
type, text
------------------
car , long content
```

Problem: here I would repeat the text of the `type` over and over again.

To change it I could use a reference by id:

```
table product:
type_id, text
---------------------
1      , long content

table product_type:
id, type_name
-------------
1 , car
```

Question: would you consider this the right way (because on every fetch of the product I'd have to join the `product_type` table to get the text of the `type`)?

I later want to offer some content of the database again as a `REST` api, and there I also want to give the `<type>car</type>` property written out.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way is to leave only `type_id`, remove table `product_type` and create mapping in your code from type_id to enum value. If you want to have some meaningful name in you db just add another column `type_name` to your `product` table.